# Can you change the virtual NIC type after building a VM?

Tags: networking, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vswitch

When building a VM, you can select which virtual device type you would like a vNIC to be (E1000, VMXNET3, etc).

*After* the VM is created, can you change the type of vNIC in use on a given connection (eg from E1000 to VMXNET3)?

If so, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can change the type.

Use the `Set-NetworkAdapter` powercli cmdlet.  The "Type" switch allows you to modify adapter.  Note that the VM has to be turned off to do this.

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Set-NetworkAdapter.html

vSphere PowerCLI can be downloaded here:

https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VSP510-PCLI-510&productId=285

It can be installed on any Windows machine that has network access to the ESXi server.  I typically install it directly on my laptop/workstation where I also have vSphere installed.

After installing, open it up.  Use `Connect-VIServer` to connect to your ESXi host.  It will prompt you for server ip, and credentials.

Use `Get-VM` to retrieve the list of VMs on the ESXi host.  Confirm the one you want to change is there, and note the exact name.

Use this command to change the adapter, replacing server name with exact name from the `Get-VM` list and type with the adapter type you want:

`get-vm 'myserver'|get-networkadapter|set-networkadapter -type e1000`

Note that if the VM has multiple NICs you may need another switch in the command to specify the correct one.

Comment: not having worked with PowerCLI before, can that be run from a Linux VM?

Comment: @warren I think it's Windows only, since PowerCLI is basically a bunch of PowerShell scripts that hit the vSphere APIs. Think of it like a command-line alternative to vSphere - you use it to connect to an ESXi host and issue commands.

Comment: ok - guess I'm not fully understanding it, as I haven't used it before. Is it run on the vCenter host?

Comment: @warren I updated the post with more details.

Comment: When using this against VM with multiple NICs, it asks you for each NIC so just use the exact command above: `get-vm 'myserver'|get-networkadapter|set-networkadapter -type vmxnet3`

Answer (score 6):

As you might be learning there are a number of ways to change the adapter type. One caveat to remember relates to MAC address generation.

When you create a virtual NIC there are two options related to the MAC address:

- **Automatic**: (default) ESX autogenerates a MAC address for you
- **Manual**: You, the user, manually enters a MAC address that you select

If you are using auto-generated MACs then changing the adapter type results in the address being regenerated. This means that any configurations you have, on the guest or the network infrastructure itself, that rely on a MAC address will fail. So if you change the adapter type you must let if autogenerate a *new* MAC address or manually set your own. You cannot, however, manually set the old address as the interface as ESX reserves this prefix for it's own purposes.

**WARNING WARNING WHEN THIS FAILS BLAME ONLY YOURSELF**

An alternative that I have used is to manually edit the virtual machine's configuration file. This method requires SSH be enabled on the ESX host and you be willing to bypass all the data integrity protections that using a GUI or API provide.

Before you do any of these steps make sure the guest is powered off and the settings window is closed.

1. SSH into your host
2. Locate vmx file for your virtual machine (ex. `/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/testvm.priv/testvm.priv.vmx`
3. Open the file for editing: `vi /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/testvm.priv/testvm.priv.vmx`
4. Find the line that defines the interface type. E.g., for the first vNIC `ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"`
5. Change `e1000` to `vmxnet3`
6. Save the file and exit.

Now you will have changed the virtual NIC device type without having to change the MAC address.

Comment: not so sure I'd be worried about the MAC address ... the only place it should come into play is on a specific DHCP lease, and those time-out after a while

Comment: @warren: It depends quite a lot on your infrastructure. In my case it was easier to do this than re-register the guests so their MACs would be allowed on the network. Sometimes switch ports could be MAC locked, sometimes reservations are in use. Sometimes it doesn't matter but sometimes it does and a good admin needs to know how different things work in different situations.

Comment: good point. In this case, that's not a concern, but I see how it could be :)

Comment: If you want to avoid ssh you can download the .vmx from browse datastore, edit it and upload.

Comment: @JamesRyan: I suppose, but just using `vi` seems easier. Unless `sed` is available on there....

Comment: This is true but SSH service should normally be disabled on esxi.  So quickest is going to depend on how many to change on how many hosts.

Comment: Uncontested. The first rule of Internet advice is to pour out a bowl of salt. The second is to analyze it against your environment to see what actually makes sense. With a  sufficiently advanced environment doing any host maintenance without vCLI is probably bad juju.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's productive to suggest a PowerCLI or scripting solution to this question... Too many assumptions about the surrounding infrastructure for what's a 30-second manual fix.

The answer is that you really shouldn't change the *type* of adapter in-flight. The more accepted process is to remove the existing adapter and add a new adapter of the type you desire.

*existing E1000 NIC attached to a VM*
[image]

*remove the E1000 NIC*
[image]

*add a new Network device*
[image]

*specify the type of adapter to be used in the new network device*
[image]

In your operating system, reconfigure network settings.

Comment: removing the old NIC and adding a new does *not* change the type directly - though it could be utilized. The drawback is that, at least on Linux, you then need to remove the old configs for eth0 (or eth<n>), because otherwise you just get the next sequential eth<n> assignment

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *change* the type, but you can easily delete the unwanted type and add a new vNIC of the wanted type.

Comment: that's what I was thinking the answer would be. Oh well. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: It's a GUI limitation. Evidently, you can do so via PowerCLI - see @jlehtinen's answer for details.

Comment: @John: You also *can* do it in the GUI (at least on 5.1). The VM must be powered down and you must change the MAC.

Comment: @ScottPack - is that in the webui, or the vCenter client?

Comment: @warren: With 5.1 that would be the vSphere client. I don't have access to a fully licensed 5.5 instance to check the web client against.

Comment: @ScottPack - wasn't sure when the WebUI was introduced. I went from 4.x to 5.5 more-or-less straight :)

Comment: @warren: The webUI was introduced with 5.5. Which is fantastic because, from what I understand, it's only available through vCenter and many features are no longer available in the fat client. Really leaves all of us standalone users out in the cold.